# NSIS register DLL with regsvr32

Tags: windows, dll, nsis, regsvr32

I'm trying to register DLL with `regsvr32` in nsis installer (no silent at the moment):

```
Exec '"$SYSDIR\regsvr32.exe" "$SYSDIR\mp4mux.dll"'
Exec '"$SYSDIR_32bit\regsvr32.exe" "$SYSDIR_32bit\mp4mux.dll"'
```

It shows pop-up that DLL was registered (both 32- and 64-bit) and in install logs it shows next line:

```
Execute: "C:\WINDOWS\system32\regsvr32.exe" "C:\WINDOWS\system32\mp4mux.dll"
//for 32-bit is similar
```

However, when I'm trying to use it, it doesn't work (I'm trying to create mp4 video with x264 codec, so it just shows an error). 
If I copy this command into command line, same pop-up is shown and video is being created.

What could go wrong with this flow? I tried also `RegDLL` and `rundll32` without success.

UPDATE:

I can't find my DLL registered in Registry for x64, only x32. Record for `C:\WINDOWS\System32\mp4mux.dll` doesn't exist, only for dll in `SysWow64`

Comment: You are probably registering the DLL just fine.  But you will need to show your code for the "doesn't work" part.  Also, please don't have your installer copy anything into the Windows or Windows\System directory.  That just creates DLL hell down the road.

Comment: @selbie, I'm not sure it's in that code, it works well if I register this dll manually via CL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Filesystem redirection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187(v=vs.85).aspx) will redirect a 32-bit application from System32 (`$SysDir`) to SysWow64 on 64-bit Windows.

You can

- Disable redirection for a short time with the `${DisableX64FSRedirection}` macro from x64.nsh
- Execute `$WinDir\Sysnative\regsvr32.exe` instead on 64-bit Vista and later

but why go through the trouble when you can just use the library macros:

```
!include Library.nsh
!define LIBRARY_X64
!insertmacro InstallLib REGDLL NOTSHARED REBOOT_NOTPROTECTED c:\myfiles\64\dllname.dll $SYSDIR\dllname.dll $SYSDIR
```

Comment: I moved DLL into installation folder and it fixed that. Seems like it was redirection, but in pop-up it showed right pass to DLL. Thank you.

Comment: The redirection is deep inside Windows and you cannot tell by looking at the path in a dialog/messagebox.